# Ingress is not working for my application gateway ingress controller Add-on of AKS

Tags: kubernetes-ingress

I enabled AGIC in the Azure portal and then created Fanout Ingress. But it's not working. I checked Rules (ingress-appgateway > Rules > Path-based routing) and paths are targeting correct backend pool.
when i try to access genix-health-hub.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/graphana/ , it opens.(BTW I didn't even give the path as /graphana/ ,but idk how it works,If i don't give the path as graphana, it shows 502 bad gateway error) and I am unable to include multiple paths here.

Here is my Ingress Yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: guestbook
  namespace: monitoring
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: genix-health-hub.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-monitoring-grafana
            port:
              number: 80
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

I am expecting that ingress will work and I can access the graphana site when given path only and i need to access other service using the ingress

Comment: It's called `Grafana`, not `Graphana`. Could your URL just be malformed due to this typo?

Comment: I dont know why, but if i use Graphana end point it's working. But not working for Grafana @RickyMutschlechner